# Why won't my 4 column "col-xs" Bootstrap 3 layout shrink beneath 980px wide?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Note I am testing this in Chrome's mobile simulator found via the console clicking on the mobile icon. Please see this screenshot - i.imgur.com/MXXYkzi.png  No other html has been added

The only CSS on the page is Bootstrap 3.1 css file and the style of width:100% below:

```
<div id="body" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">

        </div>
         <div class="col-xs-2">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
         Testing...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I shrink the browser window to less than 980px the columns do not shrink any further?

Why is this? Nothing in the CSS rules seems to explain why.

Edit: In other words, I get a horizontal scrollbar and I expect the columns to shrink in width instead.

Comment: Is your question that you'll get a horizontal scrollbar and that it doesn't shrink to fit the window? Or is your question that the colomns don't wrap to the next line when shrinking the window?

Comment: My question is that I get a horizontal scrollbar and it doesn't fit to the window. I expect the columns to shrink in width. Thank you

Comment: I tried your code and they do shrink.. What is inside the divs?

Comment: Nothing. Something to add is I am trying this in Google Chrome's mobile simulator found via the Chrome console - responsive mode.

Comment: You get a horizontal scrollbar because you're using `row` w/o a container, but the columns *do* shrink in width http://codeply.com/go/XAxmn4h9MI

Comment: Sorry Skelly, I have added I am testing this in Chromes mobile simulator. I will check now if adding a container makes it work in the simulator.

Comment: @skelly even with a container it still fails inside the Chrome mobile simulator

Comment: Not sure what you expect to happen. The columns do shrink along with width. Do you mean they don't stack vertically at the smaller width?

Comment: @Skelly If you try it in the Chrome mobile simulator you will see the columns do not shrink along with the width. However in ordinary Chrome in desktop mode they do shrink in width. Something about when it's a mobile device stops it shrinking it seems.

Comment: I tried the simulator.. it works for me.

Comment: @skelly Please see this screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/MXXYkzi.png The word testing is in the last column. No other html has been added.

Comment: And what if you change Responsive to a specific phone model. Does it fail on any of the phone models? Wouldn't worry too much about this issue if I were you, because I think it won't occur on real phones.

Comment: @Laurens thanks for the input. I have solved the issue, in the Chrome Mobile Simulator you need to specify the meta content width otherwise it defaults to 980px. Took me so long to figure that out! :)

Comment: @skelly See my answer, I solved it if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome Mobile Simulator you need to specify the meta content width otherwise it defaults to 980px

Adding this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Made it work.

Comment: To the person who downvoted me, please view my picture:  i.imgur.com/MXXYkzi.png, go to that part of the Chrome mobile simulator and test what I am saying. You will see I am correct.